# I have two jobs in jenkins, first job running on master and second job running on slave. both of which need the same parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

I created a job( parameter build) which is running on master, In post-build action I am using Trigger parameterized build on other projects option where I am configured job2 which is running on slave machine. And I selected add parameters as current build parameters. still I am unable to use the parameter from job1.
how to share the same parameters from job1 to job2.

NOTE: Parameterized Trigger plugin has been installed.

Comment: Please provide examples of your parameter on job1, and how/where you are trying to use it.

Comment: I am using Build_ID as a parameter and value like Build_number using that Build_ID I am packing the final artifacts and moving to slave machine. after that I need to execute another job to untar the final artifacts in slave and execute one sh file to deploy the files to server so I need to use the same Build_ID for job 2. kindly help how to configure.

Comment: I think you can't use the same build parameter, as it has the slave job build info in the slave job's run.

You might be able to use a custom parameter and have its value come from the BUILD_ID, but I'd go with the Copy Artifact Plugin which is made specifically for fetching artifacts from another project.

You could use it to have Jenkins copy the artifacts to a specific folder in the target job, and you can decode the original BUILD information from the tar file name if you need it for anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install **Parameterized Trigger plugin** and in post build action select **Trigger parameterized build on other projects**. Mention the slave job name on Projects to build,Select Predefined parameters in Add Patameter mention the value as Build_ID=${BUILD_ID}. and go to the slave job and click on **This build is parameterized** Select the String parameter mention name as Build_ID and Default value as ${BUILD_ID}. now the same parameter will refer for job2 which is running on slave.

please refer the screens[image][image]